# Wazuh - Filebeat - Elasticsearch non-zero metrics

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, wazuh

Could you please help me solve this Filebeat error?

Its Wazuh manager server. All is working, I can connect to Kibana web, enter Wazuh app and I can see there my three Wazuh agents connected and active.

I want FIM monitoring nad If I change file on agent server, alert is created and I can see that alert in alert.log on manager server. Issue is, that Filebeat wont send this alert to elasticsearch so I cant see that alert on Kibana web.

Wazuh manager>
Wazuh 4.2.5
Filebeat 7.14.2
Elasticsearch 7.14.2
Kibana 7.14.2

Wazuh alert log - /var/ossec/logs/alerts/2022/Feb/  and /var/ossec/logs/alerts

systemctl status filebeat is active, but I can see there lines:

`WARN        [elasticsearch]        elasticsearch/client.go:405        Cannot>`

This is error from > filebeat -e

`2022-02-03T12:46:20.386+0100    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:153  Total non-zero metrics  {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cgroup":{"memory":{"id":"session-248447.scope","mem":{"limit":{"bytes":9223372036854771712},"usage":{"bytes":622415872}}}},"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":70,"time":{"ms":72}},"total":{"ticks":300,"time":{"ms":311},"value":300},"user":{"ticks":230,"time":{"ms":239}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":262144,"soft":1024},"open":9},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"641d7fdd-47a0-4b10-bda9-36f29c29fdef","uptime":{"ms":98413},"version":"7.14.2"},"memstats":{"gc_next":18917616,"memory_alloc":14197072,"memory_sys":75383816,"memory_total":71337840,"rss":115638272},"runtime":{"goroutines":11}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":2,"starts":2},"reloads":1,"scans":1},"output":{"events":{"active":0},"type":"elasticsearch"},"`

And here is error found in /var/log/messages

`Feb  3 10:27:54 filebeat[2531915]: 2022-02-03T10:27:54.707+0100#011WARN#011[elasticsearch]#011elasticsearch/client.go:405#011Cannot index event publisher.Event{Content:beat.Event{Timestamp:time.Time{wall:0xc07705e669760167, ext:958857091513, loc:(*time.Location)(0x5620964fb2a0)}, Meta:{"pipeline":"filebeat-7.14.0-wazuh-alerts-pipeline"}, Fields:{"agent":{"ephemeral_id":"33cb9baa-af71-4b44-99a6-1379c747722f","hostname":"xlc","id":"03fb57ca-9940-4886-9e6e-a3b3e635cd35","name":"xlc","type":"filebeat","version":"7.14.0"},"ecs":{"version":"1.10.0"},"event":{"dataset":"wazuh.alerts","module":"wazuh"},"fields":{"index_prefix":"wazuh-monitoring-"},"fileset":{"name":"alerts"},"host":{"name":"xlc"},"input":{"type":"log"},"log":{"file":{"path":"/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.json"},"offset":122695554},"message":"{\"timestamp\":\"2022-02-03T10:27:52.438+0100\",\"rule\":{\"level\":5,\"description\":\"Registry Value Integrity Checksum Changed\",\"id\":\"750\",\"mitre\":{\"id\":[\"T1492\"],\"tactic\":[\"Impact\"],\"technique\":[\"Stored Data Manipulation\"]},\"firedtimes\":7,\"mail\":false,\"groups\":[\"ossec\",\"syscheck\",\"syscheck_entry_modified\",\"syscheck_registry\"],\"pci_dss\":[\"11.5\"],\"gpg13\":[\"4.13\"],\"gdpr\":[\"II_5.1.f\"],\"hipaa\":[\"164.312.c.1\",\"164.312.c.2\"],\"nist_800_53\":[\"SI.7\"],\"tsc\":[\"PI1.4\",\"PI1.5\",\"CC6.1\",\"CC6.8\",\"CC7.2\",\"CC7.3\"]},\"agent\":{\"id\":\"006\",\"name\":\"CPP\",\"ip\":\"10.74.37.3\"},\"manager\":{\"name\":\"xlc\"},\"id\":\"1643880472.68132386\",\"full_log\":\"Registry Value '[x32] HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\\\System\\\\CurrentControlSet\\\\Services\\\\W32Time\\\\Config\\\\LastKnownGoodTime' modified\\nMode: scheduled\\nChanged attributes: md5,sha1,sha256\\nOld md5sum was: '5df5b1598b729d98734105148103abf2'\\nNew md5sum is : '361334bf60bdd83e30894c4f313d16ec'\\nOld sha1sum was: 'c233c8ccb56fbd363c44b51a9d51c7fa32512474'\\nNew sha1sum is : '7163cffa48f1a7c0bcb4a3ddff6278ae9a4895a6'\\nOld sha256sum was: '3aad3da22f2d53e8ac33c46c73f40c3e8f5db07188d166e24957d8a20b62b5f1'\\nNew sha256sum is : 'bee8072335d870a1624a541cb13ca5085ba85646a8417d4d894deff71c3f4a92'\\n\",\"syscheck\":{\"path\":\"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\\\System\\\\CurrentControlSet\\\\Services\\\\W32Time\\\\Config\",\"mode\":\"scheduled\",\"arch\":\"[x32]\",\"value_name\":\"LastKnownGoodTime\",\"size_after\":\"8\",\"md5_before\":\"5df5b1598b729d98734105148103abf2\",\"md5_after\":\"361334bf60bdd83e30894c4f313d16ec\",\"sha1_before\":\"c233c8ccb56fbd363c44b51a9d51c7fa32512474\",\"sha1_after\":\"7163cffa48f1a7c0bcb4a3ddff6278ae9a4895a6\",\"sha256_before\":\"3aad3da22f2d53e8ac33c46c73f40c3e8f5db07188d166e24957d8a20b62b5f1\",\"sha256_after\":\"bee8072335d870a1624a541cb13ca5085ba85646a8417d4d894deff71c3f4a92\",\"changed_attributes\":[\"md5\",\"sha1\",\"sha256\"],\"event\":\"modified\"},\"decoder\":{\"name\":\"syscheck_registry_value_modified\"},\"location\":\"syscheck\"}","service":{"type":"wazuh"}}, Private:file.State{Id:"native::1049-64776", PrevId:"", Finished:false, Fileinfo:(*os.fileStat)(0xc000fc9380), Source:"/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.json", Offset:122697450, Timestamp:time.Time{wall:0xc07704f6d4cb3764, ext:510354422, loc:(*time.Location)(0x5620964fb2a0)}, TTL:-1, Type:"log", Meta:map[string]string(nil), FileStateOS:file.StateOS{Inode:0x419, Device:0xfd08}, IdentifierName:"native"}, TimeSeries:false}, Flags:0x1, Cache:publisher.EventCache{m:common.MapStr(nil)}} (status=400): {"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"data_stream [<wazuh-monitoring-{2022.02.03||/d{yyyy.MM.dd|UTC}}>] must not contain the following characters [ , \", *, \\, <, |, ,, >, /, ?]"}`

Could you please help with this? I tried google but with no success. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Filebeat reads from `alerts.json`, you can check this file to see if the alerts are being generated. Judging from the log you provided, it looks like filebeat cannot send some logs to elasticsearch `(Cannot index event publisher.Event)`, but we would need more details about the complete error and source logs causing that error. The output of the command `# journalctl -f -u filebeat` will be useful in this case to  provide further assistance.

Based on previous experience. the problem could be that you have reached the maximum limit of shards opened, by default this number is set to 1000. If this is the case, you will see an error like the following: `{"type":"validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: this action would add [2] total shards, but this cluster currently has [1000]/[1000] maximum shards open;"}`

If that's the case, you can either reduce the number of shards, or increase the limit to solve the situation right now. I'd recommend the first approach if you only have 1 Elasticsearch node, having 1000 shards is not healthy for the environment in these cases.

To reduce the number of shards in `/etc/filebeat/wazuh-template.json` check [this](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/blob/master/extensions/elasticsearch/7.x/wazuh-template.json#L9) information and change it to "1", then restart filebeat. These actions will affect the index from now on, but checking [This](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/operations/elasticsearch-max-shards-per-node-exceeded/) guide can help you with cases like this one.

Also, you can try to [remove old indexes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html). I would first check what are the indices you have stored. I suppose some of them are related to statistics or other stuff, so I would first try to remove those before actual data (wazuh-alerts-)

You can use:

```
GET /_cat/indices
```

As the indices are stored per day by default, so you can remove, for instance, those indices older than 1 month and we only keep one month of those indices

To prevent this from happening in the future, you may try implementing an [Index Management Policy](https://wazuh.com/blog/wazuh-index-management/) after you solve the issue at hand.